# How to make a Paste Only TextField In Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a BasicTextField and I want it to focus by default when the screen opens and the keyboard to be close in all cases and not open.

Basically, I just want the user to paste to that TextField by long pressing on it. I don't want users to type from the keyboard.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please update the question that the text field should *not* be editable and only support Ctrl/Cmd+V shortcut - as stated below.

Comment: Why is this a `BasicTextField()` if you do not want to support text entry? Why not simply provide some paste option that updates some simple `Text()` with the results?

Comment: @CommonsWare Because we have a TextField in the our design

Comment: You have something that visually resembles a text field. That does not require it to be *implemented* using `BasicTextField()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Ui()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Ui() {
    MyApplicationTheme {
        // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
        Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
            Greeting()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    var value by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val localFocusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val localSoftwareKeyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    TextField(
        modifier = Modifier
            .focusRequester(focusRequester)
            .onFocusChanged { if(it.isFocused) localSoftwareKeyboardController?.hide() }
            .focusable(),
        value = value,
        onValueChange = { value = it },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = { localFocusManager.clearFocus() })
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    Ui()
}
```

Just as in above code get current focus and clear it. or you can also hide keyboard using [LocalSoftwareKeyboardController](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/LocalSoftwareKeyboardController) just like focusManager.

```
val localSoftwareKeyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
```

....

```
keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = { localSoftwareKeyboardController?.hide() })
```

Comment: I want the keyboard to always be hidden and never open. I just want to be able to paste the text. Your code is not working for this scenario

Answer (score -1):

One way is ... You can specify `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden` in manifest for that activity

**Pros:**

- It does the job to some extent without much `code`

**Cons:**

- If the user presses on the edit text rapidly you can see the keyboard for some frames. Which may make users go crazy
- If you have other edit text which is editable in the same activity then you need to manually check for focus events and set this programmatically

**Tip:** If you are planning to allow users to only paste how about reading the data from the clipboard service and display it by default and make some UI changes to give options to users to go with that value or not ...

Comment: This will happen for one screen. I have single activity and I want to set this for one of the screens